# In case of textbox can readOnly property could be in toggle form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want the readOnly property for two textbox fields. When click on '#text1' the '#text2' should have false readonly property and when click on '#text2' the '#text1' readonly will be false. By default both textboxes have true readOnly. Is it possible?

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />
```

Comment: so, you want the textboxes to be readonly unless user focus on them? what would that achieve?

Comment: yeah @guri that is..

Comment: you can simply put an illusion of readonly by greying the textbox background.

Comment: That will not work for me. If you have any other technical option, kindly show me with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#text1').focus(function(){
    $('#text2').attr('readonly',true);
    $('#text1').attr('readonly',false);
});
$('#text2').focus(function(){
    $('#text1').attr('readonly',true);
    $('#text2').attr('readonly',false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        <input type="text" id="text1" onclick="text1()" /> 
        <input type="text" id="text2" onclick="text2()" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function text1() {
                $("#text1").prop("readonly", true);
                $("#text2").prop("readonly", false);
            }

            function text2() {
                $("#text2").prop("readonly", true);
                $("#text1").prop("readonly", false);
            }
        </script>
```